# Select MVC Membership usernames to list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am trying to select all usernames in MVC membership provider into a queryable list to plug into a function that checks if a given username exists and modifies it by adding a number at the end if it is so.  I am struggling to get the list. I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is achievable.

So far this is what I have come up with as below

```
  var allusers = (from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
            select new
            {
              Uname = u.UserName
            }).ToList();
```

But It does not work  and gives the error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

I have realised that the error goes away only when  the below code is in place.

```
private string GetUniqueSlug(string Uname, object allusers)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But this is the function that is supposed to be evaluated

```
//unique username for autogenerate
 private string GetUniqueSlug(string Uname, List<string> allusers)
 {
  var slug = Uname.ToSeoUrl();
  return allusers.Any(s => s == slug)? GetUniqueSlugInternal(slug,    allusers) : slug;
}
```

When the condition is triggered to generate a new uname, the not implemented step gets the focus

Comment: Your above code works i.e. it does return a list of objects each contain Uname. Are you sure you are getting exception on exactly above code line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with this instead

```
List<string> allusers = (from MembershipUser c in Membership.GetAllUsers()
select new { UserName = c.ToString() }).Select(t=>t.UserName).ToList();
```